# Proving all exponential properties from $b^{x+k}=b^x\cdot b^k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say that there is a function $f(x)$ which satisfies the following property:
$$f(x+k)=f(x)\space{}\cdot\space{}f(k)$$
In addition, $f(1)=b\gt1$. I am trying to prove the following property *without* explicitly relying on the fact that $f(x)=b^x$ (circular reasoning) or requiring that $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$:
$$[f(x)]^n=f(nx)$$
The only way I've been able to prove it is thinking about $nx$ as being $x+x+x+x+\space{}...\space{}$ n times, and then using the assumed property of $f(x)$ to break this up as a product $n$ times which can then be written as an exponent by definition. However, this argument only really makes sense if $n$ is a natural number, but this property should hold for all $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there a way of extending or altering this argument so that it is still sensible for any real number value of $n$?

Comment: Prove first for $n$ integer, then for $\frac pq$ rational and by continuity (you need that) for all $r$ reals. First you need to prove $f(-x)=1/f(x)$, can you see how ?

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is continous?

Comment: @Phicar Yes. I probably should have mentioned it, but my first assumption was that f'(x)=f(x) [essentially "f" is just exp(x)], which by the definition of differentiability requires that f(x) be continuous over all real numbers. I then proved f(x+k) = f(x)f(k) from that property [and that f(0) = 1].

Comment: You had for natural numbers $n$ the following:

$$f(nx) = f(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x)$$

On the other hand 

$$(f(x))^{n} =\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x)$$

When I have a property related to sums of natural numbers that has to be extended to real numbers my first thought has been so far using an integral instead of a sum ... I don't know whether this helps. I hope so!

Comment: @zwim $$f(-x) = f(x - 2x) = f(x)f(-2x) = f(x)f(2 * -x) = f(x)[f(-x)]^2\\
             f(-x) = f(x)[f(-x)]^2\\
             1 = f(x)f(-x)\\
             f(-x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$$

Comment: Good, so show it for $n=\frac{1}{m}$ and then consider density of rationals in $\mathbb{R},$ which was suggested by @zwim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First let examine $f(0)$:

$f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)f(0)\iff f(0)(f(0)-1)=0$ therefore $f(0)\in\{0,1\}$

If $f(0)=0$ then $f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)=0$ and $f$ is the null function, which is not very interesting.

From now on let set $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=b$.

- Let examine $f(n)$:

$f(n+1)=f(n)f(1)=bf(n)=b^2f(n-1)=\cdots=b^{n+1}f(0)=b^{n+1}$

So by induction (base case $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ verified, then $f(n)=b^n,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N$

- Let examine $f(-x)$:

$1=f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x)f(-x)\implies f(-x)=\dfrac 1{f(x)}$

In particular $f(-n)=\dfrac 1{f(n)}=\dfrac 1{b^n}=b^{-n}$ and we have extended to all $\mathbb Z$.

- Let examine $f(\frac pq)$:

By the same induction used for $f(n)$ we have $f(nx)=f(x)^n$ for $n$ natural, and use $f(-nx)=\frac 1{f(nx)}$ to extend to all integers.

In particular $b=f(1)=f(\frac qq)=f(\frac 1q)^q$ therefore $f(\frac 1q)=b^{\frac 1q}$

And $f(\frac pq)=f(\frac 1q)^p=b^{\frac pq}$.

Note in the same way we have $f(\frac pqx)=f(x)^{\frac pq}$

- Now we use continuity of $f$:

If we don't assume continuity we are stuck with the rationals. So since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, we can extend $f$ to the reals and we have $f(x)=b^x$ and the formula $f(xy)=f(x)^y$ by continuity too from the last note.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand most of it now, but I'm still not quite clear how continuity can be used to prove for all $n\in\mathbb{R}$. I mean, it makes intuitive sense that it would have to be true but is there a specific theorem I can call on here?

Comment: Check this for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1202585/399263 for $D=\mathbb Q$ and our $f(x)$ and $b^x$. They coincide on rationals, so by continuity on all reals.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$
by induction we prove that $[f(x)]^n=f(nx)$

Base case $[f(x)]^1=f(1\cdot x)=1\cdot f(x)=f(x)$

now suppose the property is true for $n$ that is $[f(x)]^n=f(nx)$

and let's prove it for $(n+1)$

$[f(x)]^{n+1}=[f(x)]^n f(x)=f(nx)f(x)=f(nx+x)=f(n+1)x)$

Proved.